# Samsung note 3 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note-3, keyboard-shortcuts

Any keyboard shortcuts comparable to their windows counterparts on the note 3?  Ex. Copy and paste ctrl-c and ctrl-p.  Looking for a alternate way despite pressing and holding a field of text.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is keyboard app in the Google Play Store called Swype which has many handy shortcuts - such as copy, paste, select all, etc. The shortcuts involve swiping certain keys. When I use Swype I find these shortcuts to be incredibly efficient and helpful.

Comment: excellent exactly what I was looking for!